# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop - DHCP DNS servers ignored

Tags: networking, system-installation, dns, live-cd

Relatively new to linux and just needed to run through something:

I've noticed that with Ubuntu 22.04 there is no way to disable the dns stub listener at install time nor run time on the live cd without going into /etc/systemd/resolved.conf and editing that configuration file.

Even going into the network adapter settings and specifying my DNS servers does not work. Systemd-resolved still overrides the DHCP-provided DNS servers AND the ones manually entered via the networking GUI - both on the live cd and install.

I know this through the testing I've done - I have my DCHP server setup to use my adguard-home DNS as the ONLY dns server to prevent tracking, malicious websites, and other harmful content. The whole point of this is so that any *new* device brought onto the network is immediately using the adguard-home DNS server I have setup to explicitly block harmful content - including bing.com, ntp.msn.com, and others.

When I boot up the live cd and connect to my network, I immediately have access to bing.com, ntp.msn.com and other sites that shouldn't be resolving. Running nslookup in the terminal results in a 127.0.0.1:53 server and a 0.0.0.0 response - UNTIL the site is accessed via web browser. After accessing the site via web browser, running nslookup again provides the ip address of bing.com and ntp.msn.com - HOWEVER this should not be the case if it was using my adguard-home DNS server(my adguard server also shows no requests from this new device).

As soon as I go into /etc/systemd/resolved.conf and uncomment the DNSStubListener line and change it to "no", restart system-networkd, system-resold and daemon-reload and run nslookup again, I get an answer from the DHCP-provided DNS server.

Why is this a thing and how do I disable this without having to resort to the steps outlined above to get the funcionality of literally every other device? (Windows, android, iOS, Mac OS/X)

Is this intentional? If so - WHY? How is this not a major security vulnerability as it side-steps preconfigured network settings.

Why are there no options in the installer or live cd to change this at install-time or run-time?

For reference I am using the iso image directly from ubuntu's website: ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso

Thanks.